# Clear form input fields after submit in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have trying to submit a form using jquery. Form is submitted correctly but it do not clear the form after submission.

here is my jquery code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){   
        $("#save").click(function(){    
            $("#myform").submit();
            $("#myform")[0].reset();        
         });    

    });             
</script>
```

here is my form

```
<form action="http://localhost/newsletter/index.php/email/send" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" id="myform" name="myforms">        
    <p>
        <label for="name">Email Address </label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="<?php echo set_value('email');?>">

        <input type="button" value="Go" id="save"></p>

</form>
```

i just want to clear form after submit but it can't reset field, data is submitted and still remain in the field..Any suggestion please??

Comment: because, you aren't using ajax to post form, and after submitting its re-loading form with setting value by this line --> `<?php echo set_value('email');?>"`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29621679/

Answer (score 0):

It's because you use CodeIgniter's function `set_value`. That will contain the submitted e-mail. You probably use the form validation library in you controller, add some logic there so that your view 'knows' that the e-mail shouldn't be displayed when the validation succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `$("#myform").get(0).reset();` instead of `$("#myform")[0].reset();` ?

Answer (score 0):

you can just do.

```
document.getElementById("myform").reset();
```