# jQuery to clear form fields after submit for text and checkbox

Tags: jquery

I want to clear the form fields (form fields has text and checkbox) after submit. To clear the form, I have created a button. And there is separate button for submit.

```
<input type="reset" name="clearform" id="clearform" value="Clear Form" />

<form id="submit" method="POST" action="">
```

I have written jQuery code but its not working:

```
jQuery("#clearform").click(function(){
    jQuery("#submit input[type='text'], input[type='checkbox']").each(function() {
        this.value = '';
    });
});
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#clearform').on('click', function () {
    $('#form_id').find('input:text').val(''); 
    $('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
});
```

One will clear all text inputs. Second will help unchecking checkboxes.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 18):

There is a simple solution to reset form via jQuery:

```
$("form").trigger("reset");
```

Answer (score 6):

try the code shown below to reset a form

```
$('#submit')[0].reset();
```

Answer (score 2):

jQuery has no .reset() method. But native Javascript does!

```
$("#form").get(0).reset()
// Result:
// A clean, resetted form!
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MR_Saberi/2m37cq2n/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I'd clear fields using a server confirmation response rather than an extra click.

```
   $("#submit").submit(function() {
        var submit = $(this).serialize();
        $.post('serverside.php', submit, 

        function(data){
            if(data == "complete"){ //server response
                 jQuery("#submit input[type=text]").val('');
                 jQuery("#submit input[type=checkbox]").prop("checked", false);
            };
        });
        return false;
    });
```

**EDIT**

If you want to reset using a button I'd do

```
$('#clearform').on('click', function () {
    $('#submit').trigger("reset");
});
```

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5zc9tzwt/2/)

Comment: Hi Fergoso. there is "var info" in 2nd line..where is this "info" used?

Comment: I'd already corrected it as "submit". Basically `submit,` is used and refereed in the $POST.

Comment: Thanks. But through this code, when I load the page now, it doesnt work

Comment: have you updated `serverside.php` with your php file name also you need to add `echo "complete";` in your php as the response.

Comment: I am actually using perl .cmp file. Any idea where I need to use "complete" in .cmp file?

Comment: you need to echo or print it at the end of your operation. like it will run through your perl code and at the end it'll fire the word "complete". Then your jquery will read it and clear all your inputs...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63385/discussion-between-user2201935-and-fergoso).

Comment: If you dont mind, can you please tell me how to do this with extra click "Clear Form"? please.

Comment: I've added it at the bottom of my post.

Comment: Sorry again...I want to reset the form fields with extra click and thats after submit...the code which you have resets only before submit

Comment: See the orange button in my fiddle. I've done a fiddle for you to show a BUTTON reset all inputs.

Comment: So server confirmation response code is not required?

Comment: ? you said `please tell me how to do this with extra click "Clear Form"` so no server response required if you are going to reset fields using a button click.

Comment: Oh no...sorry again...I am confusing you....After submitting the form, then I use the button to reset - which is my point...So submit is to just submit the form...Clear form is to reset all fields after submit....Now i hope you got me what I want to achieve....I am really sorry for the confusion

Comment: check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5zc9tzwt/3/). If this is not what you're expecting update your post with your form code for better understanding.

Comment: I get this error when i submit your form "
Forbidden (403)

CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.

More information is available with DEBUG=True.
"

Comment: that's only an example form for your understanding. It won't submit anything. All you have to do is add this below your current submit button `<input type="button" id="clearform" value="Clear" />` and then add the jquery within `< script > jQUERY HERE </ script >` tags.

Comment: Thanks Fergoso. its not working. Let me see how I can make it work.