# Vue js Ready function is not triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, vue.js

I have this vue function where there are basically two methods. The first one `postStatus` is used to save a post just after the user clicks on the save button, and the other one `getPosts` is used to retrieve all previous posts of that user from the database.

Here is the vue.js, where there is an ajax call to a controller (in Laravel 5.3)

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var csrf_token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
    /*Event handling within vue*/
    //when we actually submit the form, we want to catch the action
    new Vue({
        el      : '#timeline',
        data    :   {
            post    : '',
            posts   : [],
            token   : csrf_token,
            limit   : 20,
        },
        methods : {
            postStatus : function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                //console.log('Posted: '+this.post+ '. Token: '+this.token);
                var request = $.ajax({
                    url         :   '/posts',
                    method      :   "POST",
                    dataType    :   'json',
                    data        :   {
                        'body'  :   this.post,
                        '_token':   this.token,
                    }
                }).done(function (data) {
                    //console.log('Data saved successfully. Response: '+data);
                    this.post = '';
                    this.posts.unshift(data); //Push it to the top of the array and pass the data that we get back
                }.bind(this));/*http://stackoverflow.com/a/26479602/1883256  and  http://stackoverflow.com/a/39945594/1883256 */

                /*request.done(function( msg ) {
                    console.log('The tweet has been saved: '+msg+'. Outside ...');
                    //$( "#log" ).html( msg );
                });*/

                request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
                    console.log( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
                });
            },
            getPosts : function () {
                //Ajax request to retrieve all posts
                $.ajax({
                    url         :   '/posts',
                    method      :   "GET",
                    dataType    :   'json',
                    data        :   {
                        limit   :   this.limit,
                    }

                }).done(function (data) {
                    this.posts = data.posts;
                }.bind(this));

            }
        },
        //the following will be run when everything is booted up
        ready : function () {
            console.log('Attempting to get the previous posts ...');
            this.getPosts();
        }
    });

});
```

So far the, first method `postStatus` is working fine.

The second one is supposed to be called or fired right at the ready function, however, nothing happens. I don't even get the console.log message `Attempting to get the previous posts ...`. It seems it's never fired.

What is the issue? How do I fix it?

Notes: I am using jQuery 3.1.1, Vue.js 2.0.1

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I see that you are using Vue 2.0.1. There is no `ready` method in Vue 2.0 and above.

Here is the link to list of all Vue 2.0 changes: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/2873

As mentioned in the page above, you can use `mounted` instead of `ready`.

Not an issue, but just a note: You are mixing jQuery and Vue extensively. If you need jQuery only for http related functions, you may instead use `vue-resource` - https://github.com/vuejs/vue-resource

**EDIT: Update on `vue-resource`**

As pointed out by @EmileBergeron in the comments, vue-resource was retired way back in November 2016 itself (few weeks after I provided this answer with that last paragraph on `vue-resource`). Here is more info on the same:

https://medium.com/the-vue-point/retiring-vue-resource-871a82880af4

Comment: Yeah, that did the trick! Thanks for your additional notes and useful links :)

Comment: [_vue-resource_ was removed from the official recommendation list in favor of **axios**.](https://medium.com/the-vue-point/retiring-vue-resource-871a82880af4)

Comment: Thanks @EmileBergeron for pointing this out. Yes, we all in the `Vue.js` developer circles know about this change and have adopted to it, but I forgot about this particular answer for a very long time. I have edited the answer to include additional notes so that future readers will not have to spend time to discover this on their own. Thanks again!

Comment: @Mani Thank you for your informative answer. However, I have to offer a critique: If `vue-resource` or `axios` or `whatever` is really so much better than `$.ajax()`, then why haven't we all flocked to it madly? Stop telling people how to ride their skateboard. And just stop it with the anti-jQuery rhetoric. `$.ajax()` is a battle-tested tank that's lasted years and promises to a be a method that's useful for **decades**. Can `vue-resource` say the same thing? Remember, the only way to get to space these days is on a `Soyuz`.

Comment: @AJB, I fully agree with everything you said. I am not exactly anti-jquery. My idea was to avoid mixing two libraries, so that the overall build size is under control for end users. Vue.js apps (compiled using webpack) result in very small build sizes. Adding jQuery at around 85kb minified results in more data and memory consumption for users. It would be a lot better to have `$.ajax` as a separate package and include it separately. Remember - nowadays people view web apps on mobile devices extensively, and a lot of them (including me) have low-end mobile devices :-)

Comment: @Mani Thank you for your considered and informative reply. You make a **very** good point about `$.ajax()` as a stand-alone lib. I don't agree with the worry about the 85kb. Even on the worst network that's peanuts compared to 99.999% of the sites on the internet. However, as an admitted owner of a high-end device, you've given me something new to investigate, which can only lead to new and better techniques. Thanks for food for thought!

Answer (score 11):

@Mani's suggestion of using `mounted(){}` works on the component that's not hidden. If you like to run a function in the component when visible and the elements which are hidden using conditions like `v-if=""` or `v-show=""` then use `updated(){}`.

Comment: indeed, mounted works as page is loaded up. Assuming you do a refresh the mounted segment is triggered.  updated is however.  Although it seems I need to declare both for it to work. My specific vue file is loaded as part of general main boiler plate and works for loggedIn / non Logged in users so `navbar.vue` - when user logs in the mounted segment is not triggered or should I say the check inside isn't run but with updated  method - this is the block it calls after login